# Reducing Gap in CSS Grid UL/LI

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am having some issues reducing the space on my footer using CSS grid. I've gotten to the point where my list items are on one line but I cannot find a way to reduce the gap in between. This may be because of my centering of it but I cannot figure it out after googling/playing.

https://codepen.io/DanielPeterHill/pen/pxjpzM

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #FEDCD2;
}

.nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #DF744A;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  max-width: 1720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.left-menu {
  grid-column: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 2;
}

#nav-toggle,
.burger-menu {
  display: none;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
  color: blue;
}

.left-menu a {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.burger-menu {
  grid-column: 1;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DF744A;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 3fr auto;
}

.footer-left {
  grid-column: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

.footer-right {
  grid-column: 3;
  align-self: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
}

.footer-right li {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-right li a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-right li a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
  color: blue;
}

.underlineremove {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-style: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
  .burger-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
  }
  .left-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  #nav-toggle:checked~.left-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:600" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="nav-container">
  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="burger-menu">
            <img src="images/hamburger.png" alt="">
          </label>
    <div class="left-menu">
      <a href="#">Shop</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="logo">Dill's Delight's</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <footer>
    <p class="footer-left"> &#169; FarHill Deisgns </p>
    <ul class="footer-right">
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

My example is above and any help would be amazing! My outcome would be to be able to reduce the gap beween the 4 TESTS in the bottom right to make it look a bit cleaner.

Thank you,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

One option...don't use CSS-Grid at all on the footer. Flexbox would be simpler.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #FEDCD2;
}

.footer {
  /* not required for demo 
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  */
  background-color: #DF744A;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
}

.footer-left {
  grid-column: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

.footer-right {
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.footer-right li {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: .25em;
  /* manages spacing */
}

.footer-right li a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-right li a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
  color: blue;
}

.underlineremove {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <footer>
    <p class="footer-left"> &#169; FarHill Deisgns </p>
    <ul class="footer-right">
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you must use CSS-Grid, then consider a two column grid and flex the `ul`...

```
footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr auto;

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #FEDCD2;
}

.footer {
  /* not required for demo 
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  */
  background-color: #DF744A;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

.footer-left {
  grid-column: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

.footer-right {
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.footer-right li {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: .25em;
}

.footer-right li a {
  color: white;
}

.footer-right li a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
  color: blue;
}

.underlineremove {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <footer>
    <p class="footer-left"> &#169; FarHill Deisgns </p>
    <ul class="footer-right">
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="underlineremove">TEST</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Again this is amazing thank you so much! The issue I had with the flexbox was that I wasn't sure exactly how to get it to "fix" at the bottom using flex without classing up the whole body.

I'm not sure if I'm not at that point of learning yet or what but I'll try to learn so thank you for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.footer-right
  {
    grid-column: 3;
    align-self: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50px); 
    grid-row-gap: 50px; 
  }
```

I changed grid template columns to this `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50px);` to give to the columns 50px width. But, if this does not suite you, you can always use some other width in % or in some other measure.

Comment: That is amazing thank you! Would you know the best way to put it right over to the right? I've tried align-self:right and changing grid column to 4 but it's struggling to work.